# Iframe keep-alive function - what is needed to reset the session timeout?

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

I have a hidden iframe that refreshes every now and then, in order to keep the ASP.NET session up and running, for as long as the user is online.

However, I have been getting reports of users experiencing session timeouts, so now I am in doubt of what is needed to reset the session timer.

The hidden iframe's content page (simple html page) refreshes itself at a certain interval, which is significantly less than the session timeout.

My question is: Is it enough (for the session timer to reset) to let the page refresh itself, even when the server responds with a HTTP/1.x 304 Not Modified?

Is it simply the GET request itself that tells the webserver to reset the session timer?

Or do I need to make sure to actually fetch the page and receive a HTTP/1.x 200 OK response?

Comment: Sebastian: Are you saying that a request, which response is a cached one (a 304), will not refresh the ASP.NET session timer? The answer is yes, it won't refresh the ASP.NET session timer. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do to keep the session alive is send a request to a page from the current session. You can do this via iframes, or via ajax.

If you simply refresh the page in the IFrame, the response may be a cached one - thus the 304. You have to send a fresh request every time -

```
var url = "http://domain.com/defibrillator.aspx?" + (new Date()).getTime();
```

E.g.

```
http://domain.com/defibrillator.aspx?1556467987987
http://domain.com/defibrillator.aspx?5448796497878
http://domain.com/defibrillator.aspx?4123165487987
....
```

### EDIT 1

Or you can use the [Refresh HTTP header attribute](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/Session_Defibrillator.aspx).

### EDIT 1.1

If you are using the codeproject article mentioned above, then try to model it using AJAX instead of iframes - it would save you a few bytes of extra iframe markup.

### EDIT 2 - About [HTTP 304 Not Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> If the client has performed a
>   conditional GET request and access is
>   allowed, but the document has not been
>   modified, the server SHOULD respond
>   with this status code. The 304
>   response MUST NOT contain a
>   message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line
>   after the header fields.

This means that the request hasn't reached the ASP.NET pipeline, and has directly been served by IIS itself. ASP.NET environment doesn't know that a request has been made. So, it won't perform the session renewal.

Comment: Do I read your answer correctly?: Are you saying that a request, which response is a cached one (a 304), will not refresh the ASP.NET session timer? This is exactly the core of my question, so please forgive me for being so explicit.

Comment: Brilliant. This explains why, in this specific project, users are experiencing timeouts - other projects I've worked on, has had a different caching approach, often "no caching".

Thank you very much.