# MVC 4 Session Timeouts, Ajax polling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout

I'm looking for a way to prevent the SessionState from refreshing when I make an AJAX post to a controller.

This controller returns a JSON true/false object if the SessionState has expired.

```
Public Class JsonController
    Inherits BaseController

    Function SessionCheck()
        If Session("Contact") Is Nothing Then
            Return Json(JsonResponseFactory.ErrorResponse("Invalid contact"))
        End If
        Return Json(JsonResponseFactory.SuccessResponse())
    End Function

End Class
```

Javascript:

```
function session_check_function() {
    if (!session_check_complete)
        return;
    session_check_complete = false;
    jQuery.post(
        base_url + 'json/SessionCheck',
        {},
        function (data) {
            if (!data.Success) {
                jQuery('#session-modal').modal('show');
            } else {
                jQuery('#session-modal').modal('hide');
            }
            session_check_complete = true;
        }
    ).fail(function () {
        jQuery('#session-modal').modal('show');
        session_check_complete = true;
    });
}

var session_check_complete = true;
var session_check = setInterval(function () { session_check_function(); }, 2500);
```

The problem is the session keeps refreshing everytime I do a POST to the controller, I don't want it to refresh.

Comment: Check out this question on keeping session alive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270910/iframe-keep-alive-function-what-is-needed-to-reset-the-session-timeout

Comment: @Kamyar the problem is the session keeps refreshing everytime I do a POST to the controller, I don't want it to refresh.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Sessionstate` attribute on your controller to prevent it from refreshing session time out.

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class JsonController : BaseController
```

Or in VB.Net:

```
<SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)>
Public Class JsonController Inherits BaseController
```

Of course, this is set on the controller, so any other method in that controller does not refresh session timeout as well.

**Update:**
After digging a bit, I found [this article](http://sapoval.org/per-action-custom-sessionstateattribute) which introduces a way to define session state behavior per action method. Another solution can be found at [Disable Session state per-request in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1464203/337294)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried something similar but unfortunately that disables the entire Session and I cannot check if a variable in the Session exists.

Comment: I could be wrong. I don't think you can disable session refresh and access it at the same time.

Comment: Okay well thanks for your help, if I use the SessionState attribute and I get the Session from System.Web.HttpContext.Session ?

Comment: Don't think that could make any difference.